# Find js URL and replace it to js file with Regex

Tags: regex

I have a config file,How can I find all the js URL?
The js URL like this :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/xxx.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/rrrxxxrrr.js

And replace the URL to js file ,like this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/xxx.js to xxx.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/rrrxxxrrr.js to rrrxxxrrr.js

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in is replacing everything up until the last `/` of a URL, you could use the following expression: `/https?:\/\/[^\s]+\//gi` (replacing it with an empty string).

Example:

```js
const exp = /https?:\/\/[^\s]+\//gi;
const input = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/xxx.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File/rrrxxxrrr.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xx/Script/master/File
http://raw.githubusercontent.com/rrrxxxrrr.js`;

console.log(input.replace(exp, ''));
```